# How to value pass option to input ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="referral.organization" ng-options="b for b in organizations"></select>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.organizations = ['Moo Milk','Silver Dairy'];
    $scope.referral = {
        organization: $scope.organizations[0]
    };
}         
</script>
<input name="job_description" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;" ng-model="req_data.job_description" value="{{referral}}" placeholder="Quantity" type="text" />
```

This is my code I just want to pass option value into input ng-model.

Comment: Where is your option value ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly you want what's selected in the dropdown list above to be populated in the input field below?

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="referral.organization" ng-options="b for b in organizations"></select>
    <input name="job_description" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;" ng-model="req_data.job_description" ng-value="referral.organization[0]" placeholder="Quantity" type="text" />
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.organizations = ['Moo Milk','Silver Dairy'];
    $scope.referral = {
        organization: $scope.organizations[0]
    };
}         
</script>
```

Try this, be sure to put both `select` and `input` into the same controller as I have above.